# values are always zero in a plot

Tags: excel, plot, excel-formula, charts

I have a column in Excel with some values imported from a CSV file. I set the *Number* format to all the cells, but when I try to plot the data in a bar chart, the values are all zeroes.
I noticed that when I select the formula bar of a value and then click Enter, the value is correctly shown in the chart.

I want Excel to automatically read all the values correctly, any help?

Comment: From what you describe, all those cells contain strings that only look like numbers.   You'll need to revise your import process to stop that from happening

Comment: Setting a format on a cell does not actually change the contents of the cell from Excel's perspective.  It only changes what is displayed for the user to understand.  If your cell contains digits that are stored as strings, you have two options.  1)  send the column through a math operation that does not change the value (ie +0) 2) use text to columns and set the value of the destination column to a number

Comment: Thanks, I copied all the values in a new column with +0 formula. Now Excel read them properly.